# Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_mozilla_greetings_RustGreetings_greeting

Tags: android, rust, java-native-interface

I'm trying to replicate the [this](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html) tutorial for building and using Rust lib in Android app, I build the library successful, and uploaded the generated libs [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18_dmyrmA68upP1mEksHX7t3_J6l1c5-i/view?usp=sharing)

The function required to be called by Android using the `Java_<Package>_Class_function` theme is:

```
Java_com_mozilla_greetings_RustGreetings_greeting
```

My android app structure is as below:

[image]

I'm getting the below error at my JNI wrapper:

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function
>   Java_com_mozilla_greetings_RustGreetings_greeting

The JNI wrapper is:

```
package com.mozilla.greetings;

public class RustGreetings {

    private static native String greeting(final String pattern);

    public String sayHello(String to) {
        return greeting(to);
    }
}
```

And the main class is:

```
package com.mozilla.greetings;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GreetingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("greetings");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_greetings);

        RustGreetings g = new RustGreetings();
        String r = g.sayHello("world");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.greetingField)).setText(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `extern "C"` for the function in your cpp source?

Comment: The library seems to be OK, I don't see issues with name mangling. I would suggest moving `static` with `loadLibrary()` into the class with native methods (this is pretty common approach), and then try troubleshooting linkage with `java -verbose:jni`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using `JNA` whcih I think is slower than `JNI`, I'll write my solution below using `JNA` hoping someone provide the required fix using `JNI`

My app structure is as below, using `kotlin`:

- I added the `libjnidispatch.so` to each library build folder, , this can be obtained by extracted the requiredandroid architecture from [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/4.5.0/dist), download the required jar, then extract it to get the `libjnidispatch.so`
- I created interbface for `jna`

JNA.kt

```
package com.mozilla.greetings

import com.sun.jna.Library

   interface JNA : Library {
      fun rust_greeting(pattern: String): String
   }
```

3. I created wrapper for jna, RustGreetings.kt:

   ```
   package com.mozilla.greetings

   import com.sun.jna.Native

   class RustGreetings {

   fun sayHello(to: String): String =
           Native.loadLibrary<JNA>("greetings", JNA::class.java).rust_greeting(to)
   }
   ```
4. Main activity, GreetingsActivity.kt:

   ```
   package com.mozilla.greetings

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.os.Bundle
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_greetings.*


   class GreetingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_greetings)

       val g = RustGreetings()
       val r = g.sayHello("Rust")
       greetingField.text = r
   }

   companion object {
       init {
           System.loadLibrary("greetings")
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Note:
In order to avoid using `findViewById` I used kotlin extension, as explained [here](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/goodbye-findviewbyid-say-hello-to-synthetic-binding-in-kotlin-d3727bd8438e) and addeding the below to the `build.gradle` (module):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

**UPDATE**

It looks it is an IDE issue nothing with the code, the app had been executed.
I re-wrote it using Kotlin, and it was executed smoothly as well, below my kotlin code:

GreetingsActivity.kt

```
package com.mozilla.greetings

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_greetings.*

class GreetingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_greetings)

        val g = RustGreetings()
        val r = g.sayHello("My Rust")
        greetingField.text = r
    }

    companion object {

        init {
            System.loadLibrary("greetings")
        }
    }
}
```

RustGreetings.kt

```
package com.mozilla.greetings

class RustGreetings {

    private external fun greeting(pattern: String): String

    fun sayHello(to: String): String = greeting(to)
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mozilla.greetings"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

activity_greetings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".GreetingsActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/greetingField"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below structure and execution, , the apk is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j5gru4XCsOT4JSIhohdlJeaH6_SqBlgg):

[image]